# how to search for a specific word index delimited by a space ? in Perl Regex

Tags: regex, perl, field, extract

I have a logfile like

field1 field2 field3 field4withvariablelength ... field5with...

Is there a way to extract for example field 5 using perl regex, like

"Delimit with spaces" and "Give me index 5" ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can use [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to delimit by space:

```
my (@fields) = split /\s+/;
print $fields[4];
```

Here's a full test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    my (@fields) = split /\s+/;
    print $fields[4];
}    


__DATA__
field1 field2 field3 field4withvariablelength... field5with...
```

Answer (score 0):

or like so:

```
my $str = "field1 field2 field3 field4withvariablelength ... field5with...";
$str =~ m/field5(.*)$/i;
print $1; # type with...
```

if u have to other field:

```
$str =~ m/\s+field4(.*)\s+/i;
print $1; # type withvariable...
```

Comment: That's not what the asker wants. What he wants is this: `"Delimit with spaces" and "Give me index 5"`

Comment: Oh, then I've misunderstood on it